# Simplifying SAS code (if statement) using macro

Tags: sas

I have a variable x with values from 1 to 390. I need to group it in intervals of 5, 
in other words
    if x<6 then interval=1; 
    if x>5 and X<11then interval=2; 
    if x>10 and x<16 then interval=3; etc.

What is a shorter way of writing this code without having to repeat this if statement all the way to x=390?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a bit too basic, but ok.

```
interval = ceil(x/5);
```